# Redirect to WebPage using Process.Start() from Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have created asmx web service, **I want to redirect to web form using "Process"** **method for some time and return to Web Service again**. I want to redirect to web page with Session values using "Process".

**Note : I want to redirect to Web Form for some time and want to return to web service again.**

Is it possible to do it?

Here is my code:

```
[WebMethod]
public string start(string id, string name)
{
    string newname = name;

    Session["id"] = id;
    Session["name"] = name;

    Process myProc = Process.Start("http://localhost:82/Default.aspx");
    Thread.Sleep(20000);

    return newname;
}
```

Is there any other way to do that? Please help me and suggest me.

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not possible. The attempt that you have made will, at best, open a browser window on the server not the client. You will need to make the app that calls the web service do the redirect.

Comment: Dave becker, java client wants to call it and wants to return some value. Is it possible with some other way? Some alternatives? Thanks

Comment: none that I know of I'm afraid

Comment: I know HttpContext.current.Response.Redirect("~\Default.aspx"); but do you know how to return from we page to web service?.please help me bro!!

Comment: Response.Redirect() will just send an HTTP 302 to the browser, the browser will then navigate to the url. The point is, this all happens client side. You could I suppose, get you web service to return some arbitrary value that tells the client to redirect. but you can't get the web service itself to redirect.

Comment: Dave, so its not possible to do, you are saying!!